# how to find the percentage of free space for mapped drives?

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting

Is it possible to programatically find the free space available in mapped drives?

How to find the percentage of free space in your drive using ms-dos.
It may be easy to find the free space for a drive in ur hard disc but i need to find the free-space of mapped drives.

I have mapped some file servers in my systems.

It is possible to see this in My Computer, but how do show it in a command prompt?

Comment: You can't really speak of ms-dos when you're on a windows > 98.

Comment: Yeah, please specify your platform. And what exactly do you mean by "Mapped" drives?

Comment: Changed tags and cleaned up question, assuming windows command prompt.

Comment: Windows platform win XP.

Comment: i have file servers mapped using tools map network drive option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(Taken from an old answer of mine over at Server Fault)*

The easiest way to reliably get at the free disk space is using WMI. When trying to parse the output of `dir` you get all kinds of funny problems, at the very least with versions of Windows in other languages. You can use `wmic` to query the free space on a drive:

```
wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace
```

This will output something like

```
FreeSpace
197890965504
```

You can force this into a single line by adding the `/format:value` switch:

```
> wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value

FreeSpace=197890965504
```

There are a few empty lines there, though (around three or four) which don't lend themselves well for processing. Luckily the `for` command can remove them for us when we do tokenizing:

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%x
```

The nice thing here is that since we're only using the second token all empty lines (that don't have a second token) get ignored.

Remember to double the `%` signs when using this in a batch file:

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
```

You can now use the free space which is stored in the environment variable `%FreeSpace%`.

---

Getting percentages now is a little tricky since batch files only support 32-bit integers for calculation. However, you probably don't need to calculate this to the byte; I think megabytes are quite enough:

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace /format:value`) do set FreeSpace=%%x
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=2" %%x in (`wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get Size /format:value`) do set Size=%%x
set FreeMB=%FreeSpace:~0,-6%
set SizeMB=%Size:~0,-6%
set /a Percentage=100 * FreeMB / SizeMB
echo C: is %Percentage% % free
```

This should work unless your volumes get larger than 20 TiB.

Comment: gr8 thank u ..actually the answer is 7.79 it displays as 7 can it be displayed in float ?

Comment: @aru: Not as such, no. cmd only supports integer calculations. You can multiply by 10000 instead of 100 and insert a decimal point manually, though. However, then the free size may not exceed 200 GiB.

Answer (score 1):

You need [GetDiskFreeSpaceEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28VS.85%29.aspx). Works with drives, mapped drives, etc.

```
ULARGE_INTEGER free;
ULARGE_INTEGER total;
ULARGE_INTEGER totalFree;
BOOL           ok;

ok = GetDiskSpaceFreeEx(path, &free, &total, &totalFree);
if (ok)
{
// do your sums here, then printf the result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the best was powershell:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select Name, Root, @{n="Used in GB";e=
{[math]::Round($_.Used/1GB,2)}}, @{n="Free in GB";e=
{[math]::Round($_.Free/1GB,2)}}, @{n="Percent Free";e=
{([math]::Round($_.Free/($_.Used+$_.Free),2))*100}}
```

You can remove the middle two and go back to columns and/or do a type of `get-string` function that mimics grep and keep the row version. I didn't do more than this, but liked it better than the command and any windows should have powershell.

This example gives you:

```
Name         : C
Root         : C:\
Used in GB   : 58.77
Free in GB   : 416.92
Percent Free : 88
```

or this:

```
 Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | select Name, Root,@{n="Percent Free";e={([math]::Round($_.Free/($_.Used+$_.Free),2))*100}}
```

```
Name Root Percent Free
---- ---- ------------
C    C:\            88
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in modern Windows very easily using PowerShell.

This cmdlet will return a nice table containing your drives and some info about their space.

```
get-psdrive | Where Free*

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                  CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                  ---------------
C                 101.65         65.59 FileSystem    C:\                                                                  WINDOWS\system32
D                 801.55        129.96 FileSystem    D:\
R                 443.17       2351.22 FileSystem    R:\
X                 119.28        104.29 FileSystem    X:\
```

Probably the easiest and shortest way to get what you're looking for.  Remember to launch PowerShell, not cmd.exe, to run these cmds.

> get-psdrive | Where Free*