# How to assign the output value of a command to a variable in Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want the output value of this command :

```
wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace
```

to be assigned to a variable which I can use in an IF condition.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14690230/2098699) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2539262/2098699) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13109266/2098699)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get integer of free disk space in Batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106997/how-to-get-integer-of-free-disk-space-in-batch-file)

Comment: didn't know, `wmic` will run on DOS...

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace') do if not defined var set var=%%a
echo %var%
```